# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric but I have no idea why

Tags: sql, sql-server, nvarchar

I ran a query I created but I am getting an "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric" error along with "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation." but I have no idea why as I am not converting anything.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000
O.Date_Entered
,O.Company_Code
,O.Division_Code
,O.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number
,O.Control_Number
,O.Customer_Number
,P.PickTicket_Number
,sh.PACKSLIP
,Accellos_Download
,Accellos_Allocated
,Accellos_Waved
,Accellos_Label
,Accellos_Last_Pick
,Accellos_Rating
,Accellos_Shipped
,Accellos_Upload

FROM        [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Orders o (nolock)

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].PickTickets P (nolock)        
                                    on O.Company_Code = P.Company_Code 
                                    and O.Division_Code = P.Division_Code
                                    and O.Control_Number = P.Control_Number

LEFT JOIN   [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1WAREHOUSE].[dbo].SHIPHIST sh (nolock) ON o.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number = sh.cust_po

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    Packslip
    ,max( case when Action like 'DNLOAD' then Date_Time end) as     Accellos_Download
    ,max( case when Action like 'ALLOC' then Date_Time end) as      Accellos_Allocated
    ,max( case when Action like 'WAVEORDER' then Date_Time end) as  Accellos_Waved
    ,max( case when Action like 'NEWLABEL' then Date_Time end) as   Accellos_Label
    ,max( case when Action like 'EOL_LSTP' then Date_Time end) as   Accellos_Last_Pick
    ,max( case when Action like 'RATED' then Date_Time end) as      Accellos_Rating
    ,max( case when Action like 'SHIPPED' then Date_Time end) as    Accellos_Shipped
    ,max( case when Action like 'UPLOAD' then Date_Time end) as     Accellos_Upload

    FROM(
        SELECT DISTINCT
        Packslip
        ,Date_Time
        ,Action 
        from [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1Warehouse].[dbo].[RF_LOG2] RL (nolock)
    )RLTS
    group by Packslip
)RLTSS on Coalesce(sh.PACKSLIP, P.pickticket_number) = RLTSS.PACKSLIP
```

Here is a sample of the RF_LOG2 Table

```
+--------------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+----------+--------+--------+----------+------------------+------------+----------+----------+
|                ROWID                 | PACKSLIP | BINLABEL |                                                EXTENDED                                                 | TERMID |  USERID  |  ACTION  | QUANTITY | Q_SCALER | TOTLABEL  |     REFERENCE2      |      REFERENCE3      |      DATE_TIME       |     DATE_CREAT     | CLIENTNAME | TENANTID | PO_NUM | SERIAL | LOCATION |  LICENSE_PLATE   | PURGE_FLAG | PACKSIZE | UPLOADED |
+--------------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+----------+--------+--------+----------+------------------+------------+----------+----------+
| BC5A92B0-F347-4E27-80C5-49798E1B6B75 | 90214801 | PICK     |                                                                                                         |      0 |          | DNLOAD   | 0.000000 |        0 |           | E. Keith DuBose     | l:1 u:1              | 20190726 13:15:29.87 | 0x00000000207E9F1E |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| 3564B24F-1AA9-42A4-83A4-D14151395CED | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | jsac     | ALLOCORD | 0.000000 |        0 |           | Allocated           | READY TO WAVE        | 20190726 13:25:54.51 | 0x00000000207E4672 |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| 0E5B3952-2BD4-4035-A645-1C024B8D3F10 | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | jsac     | ALLOC    | 0.000000 |        0 |           | Release SWOG        |                      | 20190726 13:25:54.54 | 0x00000000207F14C6 |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| 09575559-EB27-4CDB-8B35-56F741F779E1 | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | jsac     | WAVEORDR | 0.000000 |        0 |           | Wave:2392           | RF Picking           | 20190726 15:05:31.71 | 0x00000000207EFE60 |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| 61B21B11-D638-4AA2-A94A-25B54650EBAD | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 |          | EOL_PRNT | 0.000000 |        0 |           | New Carton          | 00008139850296299650 | 20190726 15:06:03.79 | 0x00000000207E5A7D |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| 7B46FD91-A30D-4D92-A9E9-6024630D2710 | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | RFBASE   | NEWLABEL | 0.000000 |        0 | 109629965 | 029629965           |                      | 20190726 15:06:03.80 | 0x00000000207E480E |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| 042D7D42-1D08-4926-AF5B-005868924302 | 90214801 | 3F88082A | 910B2307NSZ99000                                                                                    /09 |      0 | LSAB     | PICK_LP  | 1.000000 |        1 | 109629965 | LP picking          |                      | 20190726 15:55:58.92 | 0x00000000207F04F4 |         09 |          |        |        |          | 910B2307NSZ99000 |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| 21711DE4-6119-47C0-B3F0-1A0AB816A679 | 90214801 | 3F88082A | 910B2307NSZ99000                                                                                    /09 |      0 | LSAB     | MOVE-OUT | 1.000000 |       -1 |           | 1 Packs of 1.000000 | via PICKING          | 20190726 15:55:58.94 | 0x00000000207E32CC |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| E0D5C819-DC3C-4E21-9857-25476432A057 | 90214801 | 3F88082A | 910B2307NSZ99000                                                                                    /09 |      0 | LSAB     | PICKDETL | 1.000000 |       -1 | 109629965 |                     |                      | 20190726 15:55:58.95 | 0x00000000207E239A |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| 20D981C1-CE83-459F-9D7A-1784CC215856 | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | LSAB     | EOL_LSCP | 0.000000 |        0 |           | Last Pick In Carton | 00008139850296299650 | 20190726 15:55:58.97 | 0x00000000207E07FE |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| CDBCBD5B-9DC7-4FE5-91C9-7C409EA4C2D9 | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | LSAB     | PICKORDR | 0.000000 |        0 |           |                     |                      | 20190726 15:55:58.97 | 0x00000000207F1CEE |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| DD637317-640E-4A8D-A8DB-9C2C587BA217 | 90214801 | 3F88082A | 910B2307NSZ99000                                                                                    /09 |      0 | LSAB     | PICKLINE | 1.000000 |       -1 |           | 1                   |                      | 20190726 15:55:58.97 | 0x00000000207E8F55 |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| EE4D734C-8CCE-4C73-B133-C024D79A6054 | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | LSAB     | EOL_LSTP | 0.000000 |        0 |           | LAST PICK COMPLETED | 2                    | 20190726 15:55:58.97 | 0x00000000207F516E |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| 06204BC1-87B1-4340-9712-C8996388B550 | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | BACKGRND | RATED    | 0.000000 |        0 | 109629965 | 109629965 ACT99     | SHP1563345           | 20190729 08:30:39.86 | 0x000000002089F080 |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| 48759371-8B78-4901-8BE4-749FA55E1D40 | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | BACKGRND | EOL_SSYS | 0.000000 |        0 |           | ShipSys Confirm     |                      | 20190729 08:30:39.89 | 0x0000000020896EF1 |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| 904BF8C6-794D-4288-A594-22BA93A31095 | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | BACKGRND | SHIPPED  | 0.000000 |        0 |           | USPS PM             | SHP1563345           | 20190729 08:30:39.90 | 0x000000002087F9F3 |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| ECA102C8-B7C4-46D3-A844-FBD0CFE79413 | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | sdob     | SUSPEND  | 0.000000 |        0 |           |                     |                      | 20190729 09:45:40.12 | 0x00000000208922D8 |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| 867A7B87-5AB2-4EE7-8FDC-7175D406C0F0 | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | sdob     | UNSUSPND | 0.000000 |        0 |           |                     |                      | 20190729 10:07:56.88 | 0x00000000208A0AF5 |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| E5FB157B-9837-4DA8-B5D0-9A605603FD60 | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | sdob     | SHIPCOMP | 0.000000 |        0 |           |                     | ship_order()         | 20190729 11:42:20.30 | 0x000000002089D1FD |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| 37D4B782-1184-4F91-913B-F1BA251740DF | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | sdob     | SHIPPED  | 0.000000 |        0 |           | USPS PM             | SHP1563345           | 20190729 11:42:20.32 | 0x000000002088482F |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| 4FDE75F7-D98B-451E-A106-0C9F29BADEE1 | 90214801 |          |                                                                                                         |      0 | sdob     | EOL_EXTN | 0.000000 |        0 |           | External Process    |                      | 20190729 11:42:20.33 | 0x0000000020897E4A |         09 |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
| C41D73C8-385A-4547-A684-7CEA1B7CE9DB | 90214801 | PICK     |                                                                                                         |      0 | C#       | UPLOAD   | 0.000000 |        0 |           | E. Keith DuBose     |                      | 20190729 11:43:45.66 | 0x00000000208A1D2F |            |          |        |        |          |                  |          1 | 1.000000 |        0 |
+--------------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+----------+--------+--------+----------+------------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

What I am trying to do is to get the timestamp for each part of the order. So when it was created, when it was picked, and so on. I want this information to be displayed horizontally, per order. Also, it only crashed after running for like 5 minutes.

Comment: Check the data types of the columns you are joining on. Joining on two columns of different data types can also result in a conversion error. I think we'll also need schema and sample data for all the tables involved to really help.

Comment: Ah okay. So P.Pickticket_Number is numeric while both the Packslips is nvarchar. I have a very similar query to this and it works, not sure why this isn't but would you know how to solve this?

Comment: A hack way of making it work would be to convert your numeric field to nvarchar in your join statement. Not efficient, but effective. E.g. "Join t on convert(t.x, nvarchar(max)) = y"

Comment: Yep, that's what I tried and it worked. Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Sure the efficient way is to use the proper datatypes in every column. When you store numbers as strings you are inviting performance and logical issues. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: The best thing would be to clean your data and change the data types so they match between columns that you will be joining on. I know that might be practical, but the best time to make your database schema correct is right now, and the second best time is right now ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation` happen because of the value of Date_Time that you do in max() containing NULL value.

For the error, I'm afraid that that causes from `Coalesce(sh.PACKSLIP, P.pickticket_number)`. You should check the type and convert one of them to have the same type as another. From the hint from the table, you attached they both should be the numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the warning  you can use below option.

**SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF**